# nth-last-child, must select number more that actual elements

Tags: css

just so you know, **I CAN NOT MODIFY ON JAVASCRIPT, I CAN ONLY ADD CUSTOM CSS**

I have this website
https://elt.sa

you can check the last `<section>` tag
I want to select it in css so I can change the color of it

I can see that it's the last section! but it's not getting selected until I write
`nth-last-child(18)` and sometimes 19 !

check the images below, and you can inspect the website above and modify on `<style>` tag inside header , (the second one)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is always last then you can use [`:last-of-type`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-of-type.asp), for more details check this [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

```
section.section:last-of-type {
    background: #cc3329;
}
```

**[`section.section:last-of-type`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-of-type.asp)** - it selects every `section.section` element that is the last `section.section` element of its parent.

Comment: wow!, literally I was trying for like a week and I couldn't understand why I have to put nth-last-child(18) while it's the last element, this actually solves the problem, but I still want to know why.  thanks for this great help

Answer (score 1):

you can do it also by javascript or css

for javascript

```
let section =  document.querySelectorAll('section');
section[section.length - 1].style.background = 'red'
```

or css

```
section:last-of-type{
  background: red;
}
```